# Socket sends binary data instead of text data

Tags: c, sockets

I have sample code for sending and receiving data about sockets on unix with c.

This is server code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) //server-side
{
    int socket_desc, c, new_socket, val;
    char reply[2];
    //char* msg;
    char *msg1, *msg2, *msg3;
    msg1 = "Your number is less greater than the guessed number\n";
    msg2 = "Your number is greater than the guessed number\n";
    msg3 = "You guessed right\n";
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  

    srand(time(NULL));
    int num = rand() % 99 + 1;  

    if(socket_desc < 0){
        printf("Couldn't create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
        printf("Bind error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Binding done\n");
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections\n");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    printf("Accepted\n");
    while(new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t*) &c)){
        recv(new_socket, reply, strlen(reply), 0);
        val = snprintf(reply, strlen(reply), "%d", val);

        if(num < val){
            send(new_socket, msg1, sizeof(msg1), 0);
        } else if(num > val){
            send(new_socket, msg2, sizeof(msg2), 0);
        } else{
            send(new_socket, msg3, sizeof(msg3), 0);
        }
        //send(new_socket, reply, sizeof(reply), 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is client code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) //client-side
{
    int socket_desc, num;
    char data[2];
    char serv_reply[50];
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);    

    if(socket_desc < 0){
        printf("Couldn't create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    //int nread = 23;
    //write(socket_desc, &nread, sizeof(nread));

    int conn = connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    if(conn == -1){
        printf("Cannot establish a connection\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connected\n");

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    sprintf(data, "%d", num);
    if(send(socket_desc, data, strlen(data), 0) < 0){
        printf("Send was unsuccessful\n");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Data sent\n");
    if(recv(socket_desc, serv_reply, strlen(serv_reply), 0) < 0){
        printf("Cannot receive data\n");
        return 1;
    }
    puts(serv_reply);
    return 0;
}
```

I wish to see a message indicating whether random number is less than, greater than or equal to input number.But what i see is this:

[image: Send compilation result]

I appreciate any help and before any of you ask, this is not a homework just a basic exercise on understanding sockets in unix.

Comment: Use `strlen(msgx)+1`, `sizeof(msgx)` will always be 4 or 8, since its a pointer. And use `sizeof(serv_reply)` instead of `strlen(serv_reply)` ;))

Comment: Also, note that `SOCK_STREAM` means what it says - the data is a *stream*.  When you call `read( socket_desc, serv_reply, sizeof( serv_reply ) );`, you can get anywhere from 1 to `sizeof( serv_reply )` bytes.  You can `read()` multiple messages from the other end, or you can read a partial message.

Comment: @Ctx : If you are going to answer the question, post an answer not a comment.  Don't use the comments to answer.

Comment: @Clifford that is not the only bug.  There are several critical ones and it's not easy to see which one is actually causing the OP symptoms.  If fixing that bug does not remove the symptom, an answer could be not wrong and downvoted at the same time.

Comment: @MartinJames : I refer you https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
send(new_socket, msg1, sizeof(msg1), 0);
```

`sizeof(msg)` is the size of a pointer.  Either transmit `strlen(msg1) + 1` or (better) declare `msg1` *et al* thus:

```
const char msg1[] = "Your number is less greater than the guessed number\n";
const char msg2[] = "Your number is greater than the guessed number\n";
const char msg3[] = "You guessed right\n";
```

Furthermore here:

```
if(recv(socket_desc, serv_reply, strlen(serv_reply), 0) < 0){
        printf("Cannot receive data\n");
        return 1;
    }
    puts(serv_reply);
```

`strlen(serv_reply)` is undefined because `serv_reply` has not been initialised.  Here you *did* need `sizeof(serv_reply)`. You are then outputting whatever was received regardless of its length and regardless of whether it is nul terminated.

You need to output the received fragments until nothing is received, and not assume nul termination.  For example:

```
int received = 0 ;
do
{ 
    received = recv( socket_desc,
                     serv_reply,
                     sizeof(serv_reply) - 1,
                     0 ) ;
    if( received > 0 )
    {
        serv_reply[received] = '\0' ;
        printf( "%s", serv_reply ) ;
    }
} while( received > 0 ) ;
```

Comment: Look, you did that much better than I had! Why don't you leave it to my disposition what I comment and what I answer? Now I can vote you up and we are both happy!

Comment: @Ctx : I refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment.  It is not lost on me that I am in breach of the last bullet point (as are you) by discussing this here, so I'll say nothing further.